# How to setup texliveonfly, on any LaTeX editor?

Tags: installing, texlive, linux

I'm a novice in the world of LaTeX, and I'm struggling to find a simple tutorial on how to to setup [`texliveonfly`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texliveonfly) as part of TeX Live 2011 in any LaTeX editor.

Is there anyone out there who's got `texliveonfly` setup on their computer, who could provide a simple step-by-step guide?

Comment: And yeah, I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't use it normally, but I just tested the following successfully.

`texliveonfly` must be installed, which it was here. If it isn't installed, you can install it by opening a terminal and typing

```
sudo tlmgr install texliveonfly
```

#### TeXworks

To use this in TeXworks go to Edit --> Preferences, and look under the Typesetting tab. Click the plus-button next to the list of typesetting tools to create a new one. Give it a reasonable name, type `texliveonfly` in the *Program* box and add a new argument `$fullname` by (again) clicking the plus-button. See screenshot below.

To compile your document with this, select in the dropdown-menu and click the green arrow (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>). You can also set this as a default for the document by typing

```
% !TeX program = TeXliveonthefly
```

where `TeXliveonthefly` was the name you gave that typesetting tool.

As mentioned on the CTAN-page, `lualatex` is used as the default compiler. If you want to use e.g. `pdflatex` add another argument before `$fullname` saying `--engine=pdflatex`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For TeXstudio, the answer is go to Options/Configure TeXstudio/Commands/pdflatex
"/bin/texliveonfly" %.tex

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it for every latex editor, but figured out how to do so for TeXstudio, which is as follows:

**TeXstudio**

Go to `Options/Configure TeXstudio/Commands/PdfLaTex` and pasting:

`"/Path/to/texliveonfly/script" --compiler=pdflatex --texlive_bin="/Path/to/texlive/bin" %.tex`

For example:
`"/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/texliveonfly" --compiler=pdflatex --texlive_bin="/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/" %.tex`

This changes the PDFLaTex compiler from the default to `texliveonfly`. You can change this to any other compiler such as Xelatex by changing the options to `--compiler=xelatex`.

The default compiler can also be changed by going to `Options/Configure TeXstudio/Build/Default Compiler` and setting:

`"/Path/to/texliveonfly/script" --engine=pdflatex --texlive_bin="/Path/to/texlive/bin" %.tex`

For example: `"/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/texliveonfly" --texlive_bin="/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/" %.tex`