# Installing missing packages automatically in TexLive

Tags: packages, texlive

How can we get all the missing packages automatically installed with TexLive.

This option exists in  MikTeX.  Is there some comparable way of doing this using TexLive?

I am on linux mint.

Comment: Probably should give some information regarding your environment.

Comment: There is `texliveonfly`, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50464/how-to-setup-texliveonfly-on-any-latex-editor/50467#50467

Comment: Apparently it exists, but it is crazy! Do you really want to run `<command>` with administrator privileges every time you run it? I don't consider myself nearly as paranoid about security as I know I should be, but this seems rather beyond the pale.... (Consider: do you let Linux Mint update itself without your authorization?) Besides, the easiest 'automatic' way to get the missing packages is to do a 'full' install of TeX Live.

Comment: @jon It escalates privileges, I think. I assume only for installation rather than compilation although I didn't check this. No good if you've followed upstream's recommendation and installed TL using an unprivleged user account, though. It is saner than one might have thought, but I would consider using it myself even if I had ignored upstream's recommendation.

Comment: The solution I was looking for is given by  @Torbjørn T. (using `texliveonfly`)

Comment: @cfr -- Hmm, OK, I looked at the script and I see it is not as foolish as I first imagined. However, I still think it could be exploited fairly easily. I certainly wouldn't want to run 3rd-party `.tex` files and install what they 'need' on the fly. (Of course, given the number of global TeX users is quite small, and that the users of this script are likely to be an even smaller subset, it's not the most efficient way to spread mayhem and compromise people's systems....)

Comment: @jon I meant, of course, that I would *not* consider using it myself, even if I'd ignored upstream's recommendation .... Of course, it will only install what they 'need' if TeX Live includes it, I assume. But that is scant protection since TL will pick up what is sent to CTAN and CTAN will host anything superficially reasonable looking. I would not personally run `tlmgr` either with root privileges or with the user account I work in. And I have significant concerns about running ConTeXt or LuaTeX at all for any purpose. So I'm at the 'paranoid' end of the users i.e. moderately sane.

Comment: I do run `tlmgr` to list things with my user account - it isn't really `tlmgr` I'm worried about. But mostly I run it only from a dedicated account. It is no more work than running it with `sudo` or after `su`. The initial set up takes a few minutes. After that, no difference. I occasionally run LuaTeX for examples here, but only if I'm sure I understand the code. I don't like it. @jon It is a complete myth that there's anything difficult about managing a TeX install without root privileges.