# TeXStudio on ubuntu, how to set it up so it find packages on ctan?

Tags: texstudio, ubuntu, ctan

Well I just started using TeXStudio on ubuntu, after having used it for years on windows.

On windows whenever a package is missing TexStudio will ask me to download that package from ctan (if it is available there), however on ubuntu this seems to be missing.

For example a simple documentclass `hitec` is missing, and it errors without giving me an option to set the search repositories.

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything at all to do with TeXStudio, but the TeX distribution. The autoinstallation on Windows is a feature of MikTeX, while you're probably running some version of TeX Live on Ubuntu. There does exist a method for automatic package installation in TeX Live, `texliveonfly`.  See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50464/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291317/  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463842/

Comment: @TorbjørnT. well on windows texstudio indeed automatically installed miktex. However I have a hard time finding what texstudio actually uses under the hood.

Comment: If you look in the `.log` file of any `.tex` document you've compiled, it's written in the very first line.

Comment: just use `tlmgr install hitec` and it will be installed in texlive.